# Make a function that is declared in an autoloaded, namespaced class file, into a global function

Tags: php, function, namespaces, composer-php, global-namespace

My requirement might seem like awful practice, but none the less I would like to know if it's doable.

I'm using composer to autoload my classes. In one of the class files, I want to define a function that can be used as a shorthand within the global namespace. Because of composer's requirements, the class needs to be namespaced.

**My question**: Is there any way via minor alterations that I could get this working?

#### MyClass.php:

```
<?php

namespace Jodes;

class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "I am the class";
    }
}

function fn(){
    echo "I am a shorthand for doing stuff";
}
```

#### index.php:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Jodes\MyClass;

new MyClass();

// Jodes\fn();  // works
// fn();        // doesn't work
```

#### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "jodes/mypackage",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Jodes\\" : "src"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of without luck, despite reading more links than I can count.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, if this function is not a part of **MyClass**, it shouldn't be put in the same file. The convention is to put each class (and only that class) in separate files.

For helper function like your **fn()** that should be available globally, you're gonna need a separate file. Declare the function there in the global namespace, and then add to your composer project using composer's **files** mechanism:

```
//common.php
<?php
function fn() {
  // some code
}

//composer.json
"autoload": {
    "files": ["path/to/common.php"]
}
```

This will load your **common.php** file for every request and make your helper functions available.

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.6+ you can go one step further and define the namespace for your helper function. That will avoid any naming conflicts - and you can import that function where you use it so you can still call it simply as fn().  Much better IMHO than adding it to the global namespace.